# Avoid null to enter into list

Tags: c#, .net, list, lambda, anonymous-methods

Please see the code below

```
1. persons = Items.Select(item => componentResolver.ResolvePerson(new TridionUri(item.Id))).ToList();
2. persons.Each(person => person.AdditionalInfo); // gives null reference exception
```

ResolvePerson looks like:

```
public Person ResolvePerson(TridionUri personUri)
{
    Person person = publicationResolverService.GetPerson(personUri);
    if (author != null)
    {
        person.Id = personUri.ItemId.ToString();
    }
    return person;
}
```

Now the problem is that, 'Items' contain an ID for which person is not there. So my 'ResolvePerson' returns a null. This leads to an exception in line#2. I only have control to ResolvePerson method. Is there a way I can skip the personUri for which no person is there instead of returning null?

Comment: `Each` is `IEnumerable` extension or its typo in `ForEach`?

Comment: IEnumerable extension.

Comment: Then just use solution by @wudzik

Comment: It seems like nobody really reads the questions around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter out the null items before calling the second line using a where clause. But if you can't control that code like you said you can return a "fake" `Person` that knows it's fake and does nothing when you call `AdditionalInfo`

```
Person person = publicationResolverService.GetPerson(personUri);
if (author != null)
{
    person.Id = personUri.ItemId.ToString();
}
else
{
    person = _fakePerson;
}
return person;
```

Comment: What is this _fakePerson ?? Is it an object I will have to create of Person class?

Comment: @RossCooper this is basically a hack, so it depends on what AdditionalInfo does. You can't filter out the nulls but you can create an instance of `Person` that doesn't do anything when AdditionalInfo is called. That requires changing the implementaion of `Person` of course.

Comment: @RossCooper it would be easier if you showed us the `person` class and the `Each` extension method

Comment: Returning a blank instance will do away with error, but an additional element will remain. This info finally has to go to front end where a blank place holder will appear. Each method is not worth paying heed, its like a normal for each, but as soon as null element comes and it tries to access the property AdditionalInfo, it gives null reference exception

Comment: @RossCooper You can't make an instance invisible. either you return null and filter it out with a where clause, or you return something that isn't null and make sure that it doesn't do anything or show up anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Where` from `Linq` to filter null persons

```
persons.Where(person => person != null).Each(person => person.AdditionalInfo);
```

Comment: I have no control on this file. Only ResolvePerson method is what I can edit.